Text in a paragraph gets darker when i focus input element
I have this simple code for replicate this weird behavior that i can't understand how to solve, when i just click inside the input element the text in the paragraph becomes darker, it seems like it loses some opacity. Focus in and out from the input element by clicking it and you will see this, you can just copy the code and try it's pretty easy to see.
I see that with other colors i don't see this behavior but i wanna be free to choose any color i want for the paragraph.
Why this happens and how can i prevent any change of the paragraph text when i focus the input element?


body {
  background-color: rgb(57, 57, 57);
}

p {
  color: rgb(243, 0, 0);
}
<input>
<p>I'm just a text that get's weird when i focus the input tag</p>




I'm not experiencing this on macOS.

I do experience it on Windows11 Edge.

This question is similar to: Input focus causes font blurring / antialiasing in chrome. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I'm not sure what is the root cause, but adding will-change:transform on the input can fix the problem. Many times when seeing this sort of problem especially in Chrome, forcing GPU rendering solves the problem.


body {
  background-color: rgb(57, 57, 57);
}

input {
  will-change: transform;
}

p {
  color: rgb(243, 0, 0);
}
<input>
<p>I'm just a text that get's weird when i focus the input tag</p>




Interesting observation! I found that adding position: relative to the p element also removed the strange phenomenon. I can't quite make it the same reason, but hopefully someone can explain - something to do with re-rendering, but what?

@SyndRain Hey thanks a lot it works! But can you explain me more deeply why will-change: transform; solve this graphics issue? I'm not changing any transform propriety like translate, rotate ecc when i focus the input element

@Forty966996 np! will-change:transform will trigger GPU accelerated rendering, even if actually you are not changing any transform property. But like Haworth said this is just an observation, I'm not sure why this solves the issue.

@SyndRain Ok thanks, i will try to keep this in mind!

You can prevent this by removing the outline when the input is focused, by adding: input:focus {outline: 0;}. to your styles.


body {
  background-color: rgb(57, 57, 57);
}

p {
  color: rgb(243, 0, 0);
}

input:focus{
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px highlight;
}
<input>
<p>I'm just a text that get's weird when i focus the input tag</p>



This happens, because when you focus the <input> some browsers change how they render neighboring elements like your <p> text. I guess, that removing outline helps because it prevents the browser from recalculating the rendering context, which causes this strange behaviour.

***UPDATE:***
Thanks, A. Haworth for reminding about accessibility issues that comes with removing the outline form input when it's focused.
To replicate the original browser outline, you can add a box-shadow that mimics the appearance of the default focus outline or do it any other way that creates a visible focus indicator.
The reason, I picked box-shadow and not a border is because adding border on focused element causes little layout shift, which doesn't happen with box-shadow.

thanks a lot it works! Before marking your answer can you explain me why this happens? And is there any way to solve this without removing the outline? It can be useful sometimes combined with outline-offset

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Please don't remove the visual info provided by focus - or if you are going to remove the default one then please add something suitable yourself. This is for accessibility reasons.

Thanks for reminding me abbout the accessibility issues that come with removing the outline, I edited my answer by adding box-shadow when input is focused to create a visible focus indicator instead of outline. This way the text doesn't change it's appearence and users who are only using keyboards can still see that they are inside an input element.

Nazar Hapak's answer was confusing for me as well.  However, I tried by adding outline: 0; to all the element and it works as expected.
The reason could be to provide visual feedback to the user about where their focus is currently situated.


* {
  outline: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(57, 57, 57);
}

p {
  color: rgb(243, 0, 0);
}
<input>
<p>I'm just a text that get's weird when i focus the input tag</p>




Please don't remove the visual info provided by focus - or if you are going to remove the default one then please add something suitable yourself. This is for accessibility reasons.
